# How to get the link edit property in Modern UI document library

Tags: modern-experience, modern-document-library

I have a document library in Modern UI and i would like to have a link in the list that i can click  on an item to display the properties on the item in edit mode.

Is this possible?..can i use a sharepoint designer workflow or power automate to generate a link to do this

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

This is possible through Json column formatter.

Use below code in column setting which will open default property pane from where user can edit it.

```
{  
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",  
  "elmType": "button",  
  "customRowAction": {  
    "action": "defaultClick"  
  },  
  "attributes": {  
    "class": "ms-fontColor-themePrimary ms-fontColor-themeDark--hover",  
    "title": "Open Item"  
  },  
  "style": {  
    "border": "none",  
    "background-color": "transparent",  
    "cursor": "pointer"  
  },  
  "children": [  
    {  
      "elmType": "span",  
      "attributes": {  
        "iconName": "OpenPane",  
        "class": "ms-font-xxl"  
      }  
    }  
  ]  
}
```

For more details please check below MS docs.

[Column formatting ref](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)

Please mark as answer if you are satisfied.